# Access to self from the parameters of a macro that creates a struct

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a macro that generates a struct. The implementation for the struct will be generated by the macro, but some blocks of code will be provided as macro arguments. Here is a minimal example of such a macro:

```
macro_rules! make_struct {
    ($name:ident $block:block) => {
        struct $name {
            foo: i32,
        }

        impl $name {
            fn new() -> Self {
                $name { foo: 42 }
            }
            fn act (&self) {
                $block
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And here is an example of how the macro can be used:

```
fn main() {
    // Works
    make_struct!(Test { println! ("Bar: {:?}", 24); });
    let test = Test::new();
    test.act();
}
```

I would like to give access to `self` inside the supplied code. Something like:

```
fn main() {
    // Does not work
    make_struct!(Test { println! ("Foo: {:?}", self.foo); });
    let test = Test::new();
    test.act();
}
```

I understand that this does not work because of macro hygiene rules. Specifically, the `self.foo` expression is evaluated in the syntax context of the `main` function, where `self` does not exist. The question is: is there a way to modify the macro so that `self` may be accessed from the user-supplied code?

[Code on playground](http://is.gd/r0LRcE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to do it by adding a parameter to the macro that stores the name by which `self` will be accessed in the blocks:

```
macro_rules! make_struct {
    ($myname:ident : $type_name:ident $block:block) => {
        struct $type_name {
            foo: i32,
        }

        impl $type_name {
            fn new() -> Self {
                $type_name { foo: 42 }
            }
            fn act (&self) {
                let $myname = self;
                $block
            }
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    make_struct!(myself: Test { println! ("Foo: {:?}", myself.foo); });
    let test = Test::new();
    test.act();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a closure instead of a block.

```
make_struct!(Test |this| println!("Foo: {:?}", this.foo));
```

Then the macro can use the closure and call it with `self`:

```
macro_rules! make_struct {
    ($name:ident $closure:expr) => {
        struct $name {
            foo: i32,
        }

        impl $name {
            fn new() -> Self {
                $name { foo: 42 }
            }
            fn act (&self) {
                let x: &Fn(&Self) = &$closure;
                x(self)
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The dance with the let binding is necessary, because the type of `this` in the closure can't be inferred (yet?). And it also makes your macro's error reporting a little more readable when something other than a closure is passed.